# What is the difference between `raise "foo"` and `raise Exception.new("foo")`?

Tags: ruby, exception

What is the difference - technical, philosophical, conceptual, or otherwise - between

```
raise "foo"
```

and

```
raise Exception.new("foo")
```

?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Technically, the first raises a RuntimeError with the message set to `"foo"`, and the second raises an Exception with the message set to `"foo"`.

Practically, there is a significant difference between when you would want to use the former and when you want to use the latter.

Simply put, you probably want a `RuntimeError` not an `Exception`. A rescue block without an argument will catch `RuntimeErrors`, but will NOT catch `Exception`s. So if you raise an `Exception` in your code, this code will not catch it:

```
begin
rescue
end
```

In order to catch the `Exception` you will have to do this:

```
begin
rescue Exception
end
```

This means that in a sense, an `Exception` is a "worse" error than a `RuntimeError`, because you have to do more work to recover from it.

So which you want depends on how your project does its error handling. For instance, in our daemons, the main loop has a blank rescue which will catch `RuntimeErrors`, report them, and then continue. But in one or two circumstances, we want the daemon to really really die on an error, and in that case we raise an `Exception`, which goes straight through our "normal error handling code" and out.

And again, if you are writing library code, you probably want a `RuntimeError`, not an `Exception`, as users of your library will be surprised if it raises errors that a blank `rescue` block can't catch, and it will take them a moment to realize why.

Finally, I should say that the `RuntimeError` is a subclass of the `StandardError` class, and the actual rule is that although you can `raise` *any* type of object, the blank `rescue` will by default only catch anything that inherits from `StandardError`. Everything else has to be specific.

Comment: very informative, thanks. a few things: [1] That last paragraph was the most illuminating, and let me to discover at irb something you didn't mention: `RuntimeError < StandardError < Exception` [2] therefore, that second block of code _will_ catch both an Exception and a RuntimeError [3] it's interesting/odd that "bare" raise and rescue happen to work with that particular Exception [4] perhaps the rule of thumb is to raise RuntimeError to client code, but raise and rescue one's own custom Exceptions inside one's own code?

Comment: [1, 2] Yep.
[3] not sure...
[4] When I'm coding at my most professional, I tend to create custom error types that inherit from `StandardError`. It doesn't have to be more complicated than a few lines like `class MissingArgumentsError < StandardError; end`.

Comment: Very informative, but under what kind of situations that you will want to throw an Exception rather than run time error if run time error is preferred for writing libraray?

Answer (score 35):

[From the offical documentation:](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise)

```
raise   
raise( string )
raise( exception [, string [, array ] ] )
```

With no arguments, raises the exception in `$!` or raises a `RuntimeError` if `$!` is nil. With a single `String` argument, it raises a `RuntimeError` with the string as a message. Otherwise, the first parameter should be the name of an `Exception` class (or an object that returns an `Exception` when sent exception). The optional second parameter sets the message associated with the exception, and the third parameter is an array of callback information. Exceptions are caught by the rescue clause of `begin...end` blocks.

```
raise "Failed to create socket"
raise ArgumentError, "No parameters", caller
```