# What is a conventional place to keep custom Exception definitions in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

When making one's own custom exceptions like

```
class ThingExploded < StandardError; end
class ThingIsMissing < StandardError; end
```

Where is a good place to keep these? I was considering **lib/exceptions.rb**… and also pondering if it would be more appropriate to somehow put them closer to the code that uses them.

Comment: Do you want the tag "swallowed-exceptions", or "exceptions"?

Comment: The design of Rails frequently rewards putting things in certain directories and punishes putting them elsewhere. Objective advice on where to put something in a Rails project can therefore be given. I don't agree that this question should be closed.

Comment: Exactly. "Rails is opinionated software" (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and there are conventional locations which are best for storing certain pieces. Furthermore, there are several best practices guides (e.g. http://rails-bestpractices.com/) which, while not official, can also provide answers based on facts, references, or specific expertise. Let's vote for reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with `app/models/model_name/exceptions.rb`, keeping them inside the module.

Comment: As long as you only use them in a single model.

Comment: By used to you mean raise? Then I think I agree.

Answer (score 17):

I would probably go with **lib/exceptions/thing_exploded.rb** to keep each class in a separate file.

Comment: Why each exception should be kept in a separate file? The exception classes are rather simple, so maybe it's better to keep then in one place?

Comment: @mrzasa They don't have to go in a separate file if you are defining local exceptions to be used within a single class. However, if you want to share exceptions across the application, this is the approach I recommended when lib was autoloaded. However, now I would probably just put them all in one file and explicitly require it similar to how [ActiveRecord does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/errors.rb).

Comment: @PeterBrown Since they're definitely a immanent part of the application, they should appear somewhere under `app`, not `lib`.

Answer (score 9):

Unless your exceptions are so severe they shouldn't be rescued from, subclassing them from `Exception` isn't appropriate.

Exceptions such as `fatal` and `NoMemoryError` are subclasses of Exception, so if you had code such as `rescue Exception` to handle `ThingExploded` and `ThingIsMissing`, you'd be rescuing all kinds of stuff that are best left alone.

It's better to subclass them from `StandardError` instead.

Comment: `rescue Exception` will catch those as well, behold: https://gist.github.com/3c43788eabaa52ae9b98

Comment: `rescue Exception` will catch everything, maybe you are thinking of bare `rescue` which only catches `RuntimeError`s? Some interesting discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800698/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-foo-and-raise-exception-newfoo

Comment: Did some more experimenting… bare `rescue` will rescue `StandardError` and any subclass of it. `rescue Exception` will rescue any and all exception of any kind. I think I understand better your advice, and I think you were assuming that I use `rescue Exception` in my code. I do not. I always rescue the very specific custom exception, and let nastier exceptions trickle up to higher levels where I rescue all `Exceptions`, report them to developers, and hide them from users.

Comment: a year and a half later, i now agree with you :) i edited the question.