# What is the relationship between a ruby class and module with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, exception, module

In my rails app I have a **models/foo.rb** and **models/foo/exceptions.rb**:

```
class Foo
  include Foo::Exceptions
end

module Foo::Exceptions
  class MySpecialException < Exception
  end
end
```

At the rails console, I then see this:

```
>> Foo::MySpecialException
Foo::Exceptions::MySpecialException < Exception
>> Foo::MySpecialException == Foo::Exceptions::MySpecialException
true
>> Foo::MySpecialException === Foo::Exceptions::MySpecialException
false
```

1. What do you think of my file structure / namespacing?
2. Is my inclusion line in `Foo` necessary, or does Rails autoinclude those modules?
3. Why does `MySpecialException` exist in the top level `Foo` namespace and point to `Foo::Exceptions::MySpecialException`?
4. What does it mean that those two classes are `==` but not `===`?

I explored this in irb but kept running into errors that were inconsistent with the behavior I (think) I've seen in Rails.

related: [What is a conventional place to keep custom Exception definitions in a rails project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829788/what-is-a-good-place-to-keep-custom-exception-definitions-in-a-rails-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the relationship between a ruby class and module with the same name?

A class and a module can't have the same fully qualified name in ruby. It's possible to have a class `Foo::Bar` and a module `Baz::Bar`, in which case there is no relation between the class and the module. However it is not possible to both have class `Foo::Bar` and a module `Foo::Bar` at the same time.

(I'm not sure what this has to do with the rest of your question though)

> Is my inclusion line in Foo necessary, or does Rails autoinclude those modules?

Rails will not automatically include your modules. However that does not mean it's necessary to include yourself, you could just access it qualified. I.e. use `Exceptions::MySpecialException` instead of just `MySpecialException` inside the `Foo` class.

> Why does MySpecialException exist in the top level Foo namespace and point to Foo::Exceptions::MySpecialException?

Because you included `Foo::Exceptions` into `Foo`. Because of that all instance methods of `Foo::Exceptions` are also instance methods of `Foo` and all constants of `Foo::Exceptions` are also constants of `Foo` - including `MySpecialException`.

> What does it mean that those two classes are == but not ===?

`==` means that it's the same class. That it's not `===` means that the class is not an instance of itself (since `x === y` is the same as `y.is_a?(x)` if `x` is a class).

Comment: "(I'm not sure what this has to do with the rest of your question though)" -- because doesn't `module Foo::Bar` "imply" that a module `Foo` exists also?

Comment: @John: No, it implies that a namespace named `Foo` exists, where namespace means either a module *or a class*. The `Foo` in `Foo::Exceptions` is the class that was defined in `foo.rb`, not a module.

Comment: Ohhh. modules inside classes, classes inside modules. dogs and cats, living together. mass hysteria.

Comment: @sepp2k - If in the same application I state classes like `Article`, `Article::Category`, `Article::Category::ArticleRelationship`, `Article::Comment`, `Comment::Category::ArticleRelationship` I get error relating to the `Category::ArticleRelationship` class. How it is possible to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest that you move exceptions to lib: lib/exceptions/exception_name.rb
2. Rails will auto load stuff in models dir, however for the lib folder, you gotta tell to do so by checking config/application.rb and adding this:

   `# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.`

   `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

   `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think I should put my exceptions there? I think it's nice to have them right there next to the other model code.